# PHP SQL JSON manipulations

Tags: php, sql, json

I have setting in my SQL DB egz: `{"group":"622","shop":"541","ext":"pdf;mpg;mp4;mpeg;m3u;url"}`

for get param use this code

```
  $setting = $sql->dbquery("SELECT setting FROM public.table");
  echo json_decode($setting['setting'],true)['ext'];
```

how to insert new val egz: **avi** only if not exist (short code)

```
{"group":"622","shop":"541","ext":"pdf;mpg;mp4;mpeg;m3u;url;avi"}
```

or delete existing val egz: **pdf**

```
{"group":"622","shop":"541","ext":"mpg;mp4;mpeg;m3u;url"}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write two function for ***add if not exist*** and ***delete***.

```
$setting = $sql->dbquery("SELECT setting FROM public.table");
$ext = json_decode($setting['setting'],true)['ext'];

$ext = add_if_not_exist($ext, 'avi');// avi exist and not adding
$ext = add_if_not_exist($ext, 'jpg');//adding jpg

$ext = remove_item($ext, 'avi'); //remove avi
$ext = remove_item($ext, 'png'); //png not exist, so not removed



function add_if_not_exist($ext, $item) {
    $items = explode(';', $ext);
    if(!in_array($item, $items)) {
        $items[]= $item;
    }
    $ext = implode(';', $items);
    return $ext;
}


function remove_item($ext, $item) {
    $items = explode(';', $ext);
    $key = array_search($item, $items);
    if($key !== false) {
        unset($items[$key]);
    }
    $ext = implode(';', $items);
    return $ext;
}
```